# Advice - User profile image from Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am building an app in codeigniter that allows users to login using the Facebook Graph API.

I am storing user info and want advice on what i should do with the users profile image.

Since the API provides a URL for the image, should i store this locally and save the file name to db or simply store the URL in another column?

In my views, i am displaying the stored local image like this:

```
 <img src="./image/avatars/<?php echo $user->profile ?>" class="img-circle" alt="" />
```

If i store the FB URL in another column, i could add some condition to display that if $user->profile is blank.

Something like:

```
  <?php if ($user->profile == null && $user->fbprofile != null){
                                echo "<img src='".$user->fbprofile."' class='img-circle' />";
                            }else{
                                echo "<img src='./image/avatars/".$user->profile."' class='img-circle'/>";
                            ?>
```

Please note, if normal users, they will always have a profile image i.e. avatar.png if nothing has been uploaded.

Any advice on if this is t he best way to handle this? Not sure what is best practice for this.

Thanks

Comment: copy the profile image from FB.  And store it in `/image/avatars/`.

Comment: download fb image in your folder

Answer (score 0):

**after getting facebook email and FBID use this code**

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.(FBID ).'/picture');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $fileName = 'image/avatars/fbprofile_'time()'.jpg';
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
    fputs($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
```

and   "$fileName" save in your database for profile url